# R/shiny + mathjax, not rendering math

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, mathjax

I'm having odd behavior with `MathJax` and `shiny`. I've modified the `01_hello` example from the `shiny` package to include a `.Rmd` file via `includeMarkdown()`. All I modified was `ui.R` to be as follows:

```
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot"),
  includeMarkdown("mathjax-test.Rmd")
)
```

The contents of my test file (`mathjax-test.Rmd`) are like so:

```
## mathjax test

Document used as is in .Rmd format.

Here's an inline equation with dollar signs: $a + b = c$

Here's an inline equation with slashes/parentheses: \(a + b = c\)

Display format wth double dollar signs:

$$a + b = c$$

Display format with slashes/square brackets:

\[
a + b = c
\]
```

When I knit the `.Rmd` file, I get the expected results:

[image: knit-rmd]

When I use `runApp()` I get this:

[image: shiny-rmd]

---

Things I've tried:

- adding `withMathJax()` after `titlePanel` in `ui.R` per this RStudio [page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html)
- wrapping `includeMarkdown()` inside of `withMathJax()`
- putting `library(shiny)` and `withMathJax()` in a code block at the top of the `.Rmd` file
- adding the following first, right before, and right after `includeMarkdown()` in the `mainPanel` section of `ui.R`:

`tags$script(src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML")`

I have no idea what's going on! I get this in the `<head>` of the `shiny` app page when I view the source:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the backslashes in `\[...\]` are being stripped out (a common problem in markdown contexts). Are the backslashes in the HTML source? Otherwise MathJax won't pick up the equation since it will have no discernible delimiters.

Comment: Bizarre. I just went to check and `\[` now *is* working?? Inline with `\(` still isn't working. This is in the `html` source: `<p>...with slashes/parentheses: (a + b = c)</p>` so indeed, the backslashes are being filtered out there... They're in the source in the `\[` case. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: @hendy did you try opening the output in a web browser. I think it renders as expected when you open result in browser, instead of Rstudio viewer pane ( if in case you are doing so). The reason, HTML rendering is messing up if you are just viewing in the viewer pane.

Comment: @user5249203 Yes. In fact, I think all of my screenshots are after using `runApp(launch.browser = T)`, which pops open in Chromium for me on Linux. I tried just now and get the same (only the `$$` version is rendered properly).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.