# display LaTeX formula in Shiny withMathJax not working ok, how to use local MathJax in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I saw this post [R/shiny + mathjax, not rendering math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143012/r-shiny-mathjax-not-rendering-math)

I have included

```
withMathJax("$a+b$"),
```

in my `ui.R` file to test LaTeX output but I'm obtaining just "$a+b$" instead of the rendered formula

I also tried

```
withMathJax(includeMarkdown("equations.md")),
```

inside `equations.md` I wrote "`a+b`" and renders ok, the problem of about that is that inside an md file I cannot link, for example this in `server.R`:

```
output$formula <- renderPrint({
      cat(paste0("$$Kc = \\frac{(a^{",1,"})^{",2,"}}{b^{",3,"}}$$"))
    })
```

so that I can write `withMathJax(textOutput("formula")),` in `ui.R`.

How can I instruct Shiny to use a local copy of MathJax?